# Integrating Nagare project Android

Tags: android

Can someone tell me where is the restriction in this sample project?

When i put my url and run the project everything run fine but when i export the project to my project the play button does'nt start.

Can someone please help me find the clue? Is there any restriction to this project ?

Here's the link https://github.com/Dawnthorn/nagare

here the legal term

+Copyright (c) 2011 peterh@sapros.com

```
2
```

+

```
3
```

+Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy

```
4
```

+of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal

```
5
```

+in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights

```
6
```

+to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell

```
7
```

+copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is

```
8
```

+furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

```
9
```

+

```
10
```

+The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in

```
11
```

+all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

```
12
```

+

```
13
```

+THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR

```
14
```

+IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,

```
15
```

+FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE

```
16
```

+AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER

```
17
```

+LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,

```
18
```

+OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN

```
19
```

+THE SOFTWARE.